# Using awk output for conditional statement

Tags: bash, awk

I have some data with the following format:

```
 2     1  500  500  500
 3     1  500  500  500
 6     1  500  500  500
 8     1  500  500  500
 9     1  500  500  500
11     1  500  500  500
12     1  500  500  500
14     1  500  500  500
15     1  500  500  500
16     1  500  500  500
17     1  500  500  500
20     1  500  500  500
21     1  500  500  500
23     1  500  500  500
24     1  500  500  500
25     1  500  500  500
27     1  500  500  500
30     1  500  500  500
31     1  500  500  500
32     1  500  500  500
33     1  500  500  500
34     1  500  500  500
35     1  500  500  500
38     1  500  500  500
40     1  500  500  500
41     1  500  500  500
43     1  500  500  500
44     1  500  500  500
46     1  500  500  500
47     1  500  500  500
```

I want to change the 500 values to 100 only in the lines in which the 1st column equal from 11-40.  For now I'm doing something like:

```
Numbers=($(seq 11 1 40))
File=filename.txt
for i in ${Numbers[*]}
do
        if [ $i == awk '{print $1}' $File ];then
        NumberLine=$(grep -n $i $File | cut -d : -f 1)
        sed -i "${NumberLine}s/500/100/" $File
        fi
done
```

Individually, each line seems to do what I want to do, but when I put them in them in the loop, I get the following error:

`./changeRestraints.sh: line 5: [: too many arguments`

I suspect that this has to do with my awk as a part of my conditional statement. How can I fix this to make this script run?

Thank you,

Comment: `Numbers=($(seq 11 1 40))` is not doing what you expect it to do. It currently assigns the value `11` to `Numbers`.  You should change this to: `Numbers=$(seq 11 1 40)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a good idea to invoke `awk` and `sed` in the loop repeatedly wrt efficiency. Please try:

```
awk '$1>10 && $1<=40 {gsub(/\<500\>/, "100")} 1' filename.txt
```

Please note the regex `\<` and `\>` are `GNU awk` extension which match word boundaries.

**[EDIT]**
The `gsub()` function is a variant of `sub()` which replaces multiple
occurences of the matched strings, while `sub()` replaces the first
match only. The relationship between `sub()` and `gsub()` is similar to
that of `s/regex/repl/` and `s/regex/repl/g` in `sed`.

If you want to use variables for the embedded numbers, you can
make use of `-v varname=value` mechanism which can assign awk variables
via the command line option:

```
#!/bin/bash

start=11    # bash variables
stop=40
from=500
to=100
awk -v start="$start" -v stop="$stop" -v from="$from" -v to="$to" '$1>=start && $1<=stop {gsub("\\<" from "\\>", to)} 1' filename.txt
```

- When assiging `-v start="$start"`, the lhs `start` is an awk variable name
  and the rhs `"$start"` is a bash variable. We can use the same name for
  them (although they look confusing). You can also assign the variable
  with an immediate value such as `-v start=11`.
- As we cannot use the regex quoting `/regex/` to include an awk variable,
  we need to say `"\\<" from "\\>"` instead. The whitespaces in between
  are just for readability and it is equilalent to `"\\<"from"\\>"`.

Comment: Technically you didn't solve the original question, but your solution was the easiest to implement and accomplished what I've set out to do originally. Thank you! I didn't know about gsub. I did see some people discuss `sub` when I was looking around for how to do this. Why use `gsub` vs `sub` in this case?

Comment: Also quick question, how can I make the numbers inside of the awk a variable? currently I'm trying to enable a user to change the 11-40 numbers. Possbily the 500 and 100 as well, but those are less important. I'm thinking something like: `awk "$1>="$Start" && $1<="$Stop" {gsub(/\<1000\>/, "500")} 1" filename.txt`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have never quite understood the `-v` flag in awk. You edit makes so much sense, and teaches me a lot for some future applications as well.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually execute `awk`. You compare `$i` to the string *awk*, and then the *test* command finds additional arguments which it can't handle. Therefore you get the *too many arguments* error.

You need to **run** `awk` in order to get its output, for instance by doing a

```
if [ "$i" = "$(awk ... )" ]
then
  ...
```

Comment: You technically answered the original question, but it turns out my code is flawed as pointed out by some others.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sed`, where the pattern `^(40|[23][0-9]|1[1-9])[[:space:]]` matches a number 11-40 followed by a space at the start of the string.

```
sed -E '/^(40|[23][0-9]|1[1-9])[[:space:]]/s/500/100/g' file
```

Output

```
 2     1  500  500  500
 3     1  500  500  500
 6     1  500  500  500
 8     1  500  500  500
 9     1  500  500  500
11     1  100  100  100
12     1  100  100  100
14     1  100  100  100
15     1  100  100  100
16     1  100  100  100
17     1  100  100  100
20     1  100  100  100
21     1  100  100  100
23     1  100  100  100
24     1  100  100  100
25     1  100  100  100
27     1  100  100  100
30     1  100  100  100
31     1  100  100  100
32     1  100  100  100
33     1  100  100  100
34     1  100  100  100
35     1  100  100  100
38     1  100  100  100
40     1  100  100  100
41     1  500  500  500
43     1  500  500  500
44     1  500  500  500
46     1  500  500  500
47     1  500  500  500
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it in gawk:

```
gawk '$1~/1[1-9]|[23][0-9]|40/{ $3=$4=$5=100 }1' file
```

when you want to maintain the spaces:

```
gawk '$1~/1[1-9]|[23][0-9]|40/{ gsub(/\<500\>/,"100") }1' file
```

Comment: Can you explain about how that `gawk` command works? What does `[23]` mean here for example?

Comment: regex101 has a good explanation about regular expression, see: https://regex101.com/r/Y7oZva/1   explanation in upper right corner.

Answer (score 1):

with sed

```
sed -i '/^11/,/^40/s/500/100/g' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this :

```
mawk 'gsub("500", (_=+$1)<11 || (40<_) ? "&" : "100")'

 2     1  500  500  500
 3     1  500  500  500
 6     1  500  500  500
 8     1  500  500  500
 9     1  500  500  500
11     1  100  100  100
12     1  100  100  100
14     1  100  100  100
15     1  100  100  100
16     1  100  100  100
17     1  100  100  100
20     1  100  100  100
21     1  100  100  100
23     1  100  100  100
24     1  100  100  100
25     1  100  100  100
27     1  100  100  100
30     1  100  100  100
31     1  100  100  100
32     1  100  100  100
33     1  100  100  100
34     1  100  100  100
35     1  100  100  100
38     1  100  100  100
40     1  100  100  100
41     1  500  500  500
43     1  500  500  500
44     1  500  500  500
46     1  500  500  500
47     1  500  500  500
```

if you prefer a `FS + OFS` based approach, then

```
 mawk 'NF *= (OFS = (_=+$1)<11||(40<_) ? FS : __)^!__' FS='500' __='100'
```

Comment: Can you explain in short what the second pattern does? What is the use of the leading `NF *=` and what does this part do `^!` ?

Comment: _ _ is pre-defined as 100, inverting makes it a zero (0), and ANYTHING to 0-th power becomes a 1, at least in the awk world, even +/- INF or NAN - even "helloworld"^0 (zero), and it'll become a numeric 1. I'll let theorist debate the merit of 0^0. I'm only setting OFS based on whether it should be kept at 500 or changed to 100 depending on range criteria, & becomes NF *= (OFS-new)^0  -> NF *= 1, which is same as evaluating (NF+=0), (NF=NF), or ($1=$1) (the most frequently used syntax, but all 4 have IDENTICAL effect of reformatting all FS splits into OFS, typically tab+spaces into 1 space)

Comment: @The fourth bird : the typical way awk is explained to those less familar is ' / regex-pattern / { action } ' . While that suffices for most use cases, it's also not entirely accurate. It's better phrased as ' < any syntax combo resulting in boolean evaluation ; defaulting to true when missing > { any combo of statements ; defaulting to "print" } ' . And that's what a lot of my codes are - maximizing upper boolean layer, if possible, then leveraging default print. AWK "boolean" means empty-string or zero as false, all else true : (awk '0' <<< 123) prints nothing, but (awk '"0"' <<< 123) does.